# Cannot get two contact forms centerd next to each other

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've been looking at CSS tutorials for hours trying different ways to get them inline, but I can't seem to do it.

I'm currently learning the best techniques for UI/UX and I'm using Copdepen for inspiration.

I'm trying to get these two forms inline with each other.

Any help would be great.

I made [a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/gsuzfvt7/1/) which renders the contact form properly not the other component which is a map.

Here's the [Codepen](http://codepen.io/arianalynn/pen/MypjbP) of the correct working map UI.

You can also use the following snippet:

```js
var myCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(51.308742, -0.320850);

function initialize() {
  var mapProp = {
    center: myCenter,
    zoom: 12,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  };
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapProp);

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myCenter,
  });
  marker.setMap(map);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  background: #78909C
}
.map {
  width: 700px;
  height: 380px;
  margin: calc(50vh - 190px) auto;
  box-shadow: 0 0 40px -10px black;
  background: rgb(240, 240, 240);
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  max-width: calc(100vw - 60px)
}
#map {
  width: 65%;
  height: 380px;
  display: inline-block
}
.map-c {
  float: right;
  width: 35%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 25px;
  box-sizing: border-box
}
h1 {
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  color: rgb(60, 60, 70);
  font-size: 28px
}
p {
  font-size: 13px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 30px
}
.det {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 15px
}
i {
  float: left;
  font-size: 18px !important;
  margin: 0 8px 0 0
}
button {
  margin: 15px 4px;
  padding: 13px 9px;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: none;
  color: #546973;
  border: 2px solid #78909C;
  transition: all 0.3s;
  border-radius: 8px;
  outline: 0
}
button:hover {
  border-color: rgb(90, 90, 90);
  color: rgb(90, 90, 90)
}
button:after {
  content: 'Directions';
  font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
  display: block;
  font-size: 11px;
  margin-top: 8px
}
.fa-envelope:after {
  content: 'Email';
  margin: 8px 13px 0
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
  .map {
    height: 450px;
    margin: calc(50vh - 225px) auto;
    overflow: hidden
  }
  #map {
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
  }
  .map-c {
    float: right;
    width: 100%;
  }
  button {
    float: right;
    margin-top: -75px
  }
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 460px) {
  p {
    display: none
  }
  h1 {
    margin-bottom: 20px
  }
  button {
    float: none;
    margin-top: 10px
  }
  .det {
    margin-bottom: 9px
  }
}
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400italic,400,300,600);
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -o-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-smoothing: antialiased;
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;
}
body {
  font-family: "Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 30px;
  color: #777;
  background: #FFFF;
}
.container {
  max-width: 400px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}
#contact input[type="text"],
#contact input[type="email"],
#contact input[type="tel"],
#contact input[type="url"],
#contact textarea,
#contact button[type="submit"] {
  font: 400 12px/16px"Open Sans", Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
#contact {
  background: #F9F9F9;
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 50px 0;
}
#contact h3 {
  color: #F96;
  display: block;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
}
#contact h4 {
  margin: 5px 0 15px;
  display: block;
  font-size: 13px;
}
fieldset {
  border: medium none !important;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
#contact input[type="text"],
#contact input[type="email"],
#contact input[type="tel"],
#contact input[type="url"],
#contact textarea {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  background: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
}
#contact input[type="text"]:hover,
#contact input[type="email"]:hover,
#contact input[type="tel"]:hover,
#contact input[type="url"]:hover,
#contact textarea:hover {
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: border-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
  border: 1px solid #AAA;
}
#contact textarea {
  height: 100px;
  max-width: 100%;
  resize: none;
}
#contact button[type="submit"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  border: none;
  background: #0CF;
  color: #FFF;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
#contact button[type="submit"]:hover {
  background: #09C;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transition: background-color 0.3s ease-in-out;
}
#contact button[type="submit"]:active {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
#contact input:focus,
#contact textarea:focus {
  outline: 0;
  border: 1px solid #999;
}
::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}
:-moz-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}
::-moz-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}
:-ms-input-placeholder {
  color: #888;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <form id="contact" action="" method="post">
    <h3>Quick Contact</h3>
    <h4>Contact us today, and get reply with in 24 hours!</h4>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Your name" type="text" tabindex="1" required autofocus>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Your Email Address" type="email" tabindex="2" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Your Phone Number" type="tel" tabindex="3" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <input placeholder="Your Web Site starts with http://" type="url" tabindex="4" required>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <textarea placeholder="Type your Message Here...." tabindex="5" required></textarea>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
      <button name="submit" type="submit" id="contact-submit" data-submit="...Sending">Submit</button>
    </fieldset>
  </form>


</div>

<div class="map">
  <div id="map"></div>
  <div class="map-c">
    <h1>ABC Stores</h1>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Accusantium id cumque est dolores voluptatibus.</p>
    <div class="det"><i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i> 102 New Road, New City</div>
    <div class="det"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i> 001 2045 509</div>
    <div class="det"><i class="fa fa-globe"></i> www.abcstores.com</div>
    <center>
      <button class="fa fa-car"></button>
      <button class="fa fa-envelope"></button>
    </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I can only assume you have been looking in the wrong place. Make sure you read and understand [CSS positioning](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp). After that, take a look at [display property](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp) These two are all you need to solve your problem.

Comment: If you need both the forms side by side, move the map division(.map) inside the container div and assign respective width values to each form.

Comment: Thanks both. This website is such a fantastic community. I hope to be able to respond to questions like yourselves one day.

Answer (score -1):

You can use an html table:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <form>
            ...
            </form>
        </td>
        <td>
            <form>
            ...
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

this is my preffered method for getting elements inline. I don't know if you wanted a CSS answer, but this will work.

Comment: Using tables is not recommended anymore unless you just want to display a bunch of data